# How to work with a kernel one has no information about?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, livecd, iso

I'm working with a system to automatically assemble Live CDs. It came packaged with a kernel (seemingly based on `3.13.11`), that has been working without problems so far.

I noticed that, when I try the Live CD on a tablet, I can move the cursor around, but can't click and think that the reason is that the created Live CD does not pack `hid-multitouch.ko`.

To test my hypothesis, I put the one from my current kernel into the Live CD's files and ran `depmod` but, as expected, the versions do not match.

I thought that compiling the `3.13.11` kernel and then compiling its modules would do the trick, but unfortunately it didn't, they were still incompatible.

The precompiled kernel is named `3.13.11.4-vbox`, but the starting bytes look like kernels from the `2.6` series and not like the `3.1*` series (I compiled some to compare, not a large enough sample though).

I tried changing the `vermagic` string inside `hid-multitouch.ko`, but that didn't work either, unfortunately.

Also, changing the kernel completely somehow hinders the resulting Live CD from booting since it can't mount the `iso9660` filesystem even though I compiled it once with the needed module inside and outside the kernel.

---

EDIT: Compiling the latest Ubuntu kernel with `isofs.ko` builtin did the trick. Has something to do with `initrd` not accessing modules.

---

Except for the name I don't really have an idea what that kernel is about.

This seems to be a highly specific problem with many variables, but I hope there might be a more generic problem at the root.

Comment: I ended up throwing the kernel away and compiling my own, which suits my needs. I'm still interested in possible answers, though.